# Consider defining a bean of type 'int' in your configuration[SpringBoot]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

its my first time crating api in spring boot, i'm trying to create transaction api. when i'm running the application i'm getting this error
**Description:**
*Parameter 0 of constructor in TransactionService.transactionService.modal.TransactionRequest required a bean of type 'int' that could not be found.*
**Action:**
*Consider defining a bean of type 'int' in your configuration.*

Modal package:
TransactionEntity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Entity
public class TransactionEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private  int transactionId;
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private UUID externalId;
    @NotNull
    private int userId;
    @NotNull
    private int merchantId;
    @NotNull
    private int clientReferenceId;
    @NotNull
    private double amount;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull
    private TransactionStatus status;
    @NotNull
    private String createdBy;
     private String updatedBy;
     @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
     @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

TransactionRequest

```
@Component
@Data
@Builder

public class TransactionRequest {
      private int userId;
      private int merchantId;
      private int clientReferenceId;
      private double amount;
      private String createdBy;

}
```

TransactionResponse

```
@Component
@Data
@Builder
public class TransactionResponse {
    private int userId;
    private int merchantId;
    private int clientReferenceId;
    private double amount;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private TransactionStatus status;
}
```

TransactionDao

```
  @Component
    // Dao class
    public class TransactionDao {
    
        @Autowired
        TransactionRepository transactionRepository;
        TransactionEntity transactionEntity;
        public TransactionResponse createTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest){
    
            LocalDateTime cuurentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
            transactionEntity.builder().userId(transactionRequest.getUserId())
                    .merchantId(transactionRequest.getMerchantId())
                    .clientReferenceId(transactionRequest.getClientReferenceId())
                    .amount(transactionRequest.getAmount())
                    .createdBy(transactionRequest.getCreatedBy())
                    .createdAt(cuurentTime)
                    .updatedAt(cuurentTime)
                    .externalId(UUID.randomUUID())
                    .status(TransactionStatus.CREATED);
            transactionRepository.save(transactionEntity);
            return TransactionResponse.builder().status(transactionEntity.getStatus())
                    .createdAt(transactionEntity.getCreatedAt()).build();
    
        }
    
    }
```

TransactionService

```
@Service
public class TransactoinService {
     @Autowired
     public TransactionDao transactionDao;
     public TransactionResponse createTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest){
           return transactionDao.createTransaction(transactionRequest);
     }


}
```

TransactionController

```
@RestController
public class TransactionController {
    @Autowired
    TransactoinService transactoinService;
    @PostMapping
    TransactionResponse  createTransaction(@RequestBody TransactionRequest transactionRequest){
        return transactoinService.createTransaction(transactionRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TransactionRequest` is annotated as `@Component` so `spring boot` autoscan will try to create a `@Bean` out that class.

It is also annotated with `@Data` so at the time of creating the `bean` `Spring boot` is trying to `inject` other beans as arguments into the all args `constructor`, and it is not finding an "int" `bean` to inject into the `constructor`.

I am guessing that the transaction response should not be a `@Component` or at least not a `Singleton` bean.

Comment: You are right , i did corrected the mistake.

Comment: if i'm using the builder patter , then can i use the setters in my class, or it would be an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create your POJO classes as a Spring Bean. Remove `@Component` annotation in your `TransactionRequest` and `TransactionResponse` POJO classes.

Comment: thank you very much sir , for your response. i did'nt know that concept. i tried to find some the solution here, but some people were getting this error , cos they were'nt using the @component , that's why i used it. But now i get idea which classes should i scan.

Comment: `@Component` should be used only for classes managed by Spring. POJO's are not managed by Spring.